# L3 ApplicationMultipleTargetGroupsFargateService construct not able to get to individual targetGroups healthcheck

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

Try to configure each targetgroups healthcheck (path and port) which was constructed by a L3 ApplicationMultipleTargetGroupsFargateService as the following

```
import * as ecs_patterns from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs-patterns';
const fargateService = new ecs_patterns.ApplicationMultipleTargetGroupsFargateService(this, 'MyFargateService', {
  serviceName: process.env.ECS_SERVICE_NAME ?? 'ecs-service-name',
  desiredCount: 2,
  cluster,
  taskDefinition,
  assignPublicIp: false,
  loadBalancers: [applicationLoadBalancerProps],
  targetGroups: [
    {
      containerPort: 8081,
      protocol: ecs.Protocol.TCP,
    },
    {
      containerPort: 8002,
      pathPattern: '/route8002/*',
      priority: 2,
      protocol: ecs.Protocol.TCP,
    },
    {
      containerPort: 8003,
      pathPattern: '/route8003/*',
      priority: 3,
      protocol: ecs.Protocol.TCP,
    },
  ],
  healthCheckGracePeriod: Duration.seconds(300),
});
```

However only the first (default) targetgroups was returned to allow modification

```
fargateService.targetGroup.configureHealthCheck({
  path: '/system-health-checks/basic',
  timeout: Duration.seconds(30),
  interval: Duration.seconds(120),
  unhealthyThresholdCount: 5,
  healthyThresholdCount: 3,
});
```

I want to change the 8002 and 8003 targetgroup healthheck to anything other than the default value (defaulted path to "/" and same port as the traffic port 8002 and 8003) e.g. 8002 and 8003 all use the same healthcheck as 8081 as such as path point to /system-health-checks/basic and port at 8081.

Tried many variation with the escape hatch try to get to 8002 and 8003 targetgroups without much success.

Any one run into these issue and any help would be greatly appreciated.